# poweroff redirect system halted

Tags: exit, shutdown, halting-problem, power-off

I'm playing with image built from Builtroot, and run with QEMU. But when I run "poweroff" command, machine not shutdown. And "System halted" appear! (See console output bellow)

```
# poweroff
# Stopping network: OK
Saving random seed: random: dd: uninitialized urandom read (512 bytes read)
OK
Stopping klogd: OK
Stopping syslogd: OK
umount: devtmpfs busy - remounted read-only
EXT4-fs (sda): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
The system is going down NOW!
Sent SIGTERM to all processes
Sent SIGKILL to all processes
Requesting system poweroff
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
reboot: System halted
```

Can someone help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Purely commandline walkaround using reboot**

1. Add qemu flag `-no-reboot`
2. Poweroff machine using `reboot` command

for more in-depth answer about this option refer to:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/461741/447300

For SSH based solution and other ideas refer to:

- https://qemu-discuss.nongnu.narkive.com/EXlaWbLg/how-to-stop-qemu-system-x86-64-instead-of-kill-9